# read txt file via client javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm new to javascript and trying to open a txt file into var and then inject it to html div...
I tried to use fopen but I didn't succeed.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
file = fopen(getScriptPath("info.txt"), 0);


file_length = flength(file);
var content = fread(file,file_length);
var div = document.getElementById("myDiv");
//alert(div);
div.innerHTML = "";
div.innerHTML = content;
</script>
```

Comment: Is this javascript intended to run in a browser?

Comment: What makes you think JavaScript has an fopen? Where is this text file? Do you mean a text/plain HTTP resource at the URL 'info.txt' (relative to where the document is)?

Comment: You try to mix PHP and JavaScript in an inappropriate way. Learn to differ between the two first, then you can go on programming.

Comment: Short answer, can't be done this way. Javascript is clientside. Which means you can play around with whatever information you have on your screen. If you want to play around with other resources, you will have to use ajax and some sort of script (php, apx)

Comment: Did u read the other questions on the same topic in SO? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4950567/reading-client-side-text-file-using-javascript - Duplicate of this.

Comment: Perhaps you want to do an AJAX load of an external file on the same server? Using jQuery or a similar library makes this easy -- http://api.jquery.com/load/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

abandoned question:

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","YOUR_FILE.txt",false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseText;
```

by Freek8

Comment: There is no sign of ASP in the question. There is DOM though, which suggests client side JS.

Answer (score 11):

Although it says xml request this works perfectly fine for txt files too (server and client side).

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","YOUR_FILE.txt",false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseText;
```

Comment: Nice. Please set this answer as accepted answer if it was useful.

Comment: @Freek8: Common sense suggests that you cannot use `XMLHttpRequest` to read files from the client machine.

Comment: The QA says he would like to read a text file with javascript. I assume he is working client side, hence this solution works. Since it works, what is the problem?

Comment: You should not do synch calls, asynchronous is better since it will not lock up the browser.

Comment: @Freek8: The problem is that your clarification *server and client side* is wrong, as your method will not allow you to fetch files that are not on the server. And even if you run the script locally (which, as I guess, is what you meant by *working client side*), standard security settings of most browsers will still prevent this.

Comment: great answer! Thank you @Freek8! I used your snippet to read a text file in App Inventor puravidaapps.com/read.php

Comment: I think by now the File API is also a solution http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/ . A tutorial can be found here: http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/read-text-files-using-the-javascript-filereader.html

Answer (score 8):

JavaScript has none of the functions you are trying to use.

To read files on the server in JavaScript, you can use [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_XMLHttpRequest).

There is no easy way to read files on the client machine.

Comment: Thanks all,
That was one of the quickest answers i got :)

Answer (score 5):

For security reasons, Javascript is made so you can not do this. However, a person has made a workaround which may work and posted it [here](http://www.htmlhelpcentral.com/messageboard/showthread.php?9936-JavaScript-OPEN-file-for-reading&s=f2dfdc5216f7f374c186250085733434&p=55848#post55848).

Ok, I realize, it only works for files that are publicly accessbile on the server, which I believe is not what you want to do. Still, if you do find a way, it will be a hack like this, but it could also be fixed to not work at any time.

Comment: That's true for client side javascript. You can perfectly fine read files on server side javascript. For example node.js.

Comment: I found this link which explain how to do it...
http://www.ehow.com/how_5996745_read-file-html-script-javascript.html
BUT it didn't work

Comment: Yes, I realized at the moment I posted it. My bad.