# How to load text from a file to text area using JavaScript using input type file?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function CopyMe(oFileInput) {
var filePath = oFileInput.value;
    fh = fopen(filePath, 0);
    if (fh!=-1) {
        length = flength(fh);
        str = fread(fh, length);
        fclose(fh);
    }
document.getElementByID('myText').innerHTML = filePath;
}
</script>
<input type="file" onchange="CopyMe(this);"/>
<textarea id="myText"></textarea>
```

I do get any output/change in the text area!
What should I do?
Please help!

I used the following PHP code for that, I don't know whether it is correct:

```
<?php
function Read($file){
echo file_get_contents($file);
};
?>
```

Following was the JavaScript:

```
    function CopyMe(oFileInput) {
    var filePath = oFileInput.value;
    document.getElementByID('text-area3').innerHTML = "<?php Read(filePath);?>";
    }
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you want the content of the actual file in your text-area or just the filename of the file from the input file control?

Comment: Are you confusing php with javascript? Javascript, as a clientside language does not support diskoperations such as fileopen.

Comment: this was already answered before
http://stackoverflow.com/a/8137303/1781209

Comment: @João Oliveira I dont wish to use AciveX, that is why I asked !!!

Comment: @HanletEscaño I need the actual content of the file ....

Comment: @limelights I did try PHP for this, I will edit the original post and tell what I did !

Comment: Your CopyMe function is run client-side, so the php code is just a string and will not be executed. you need to submit the form/file to your server to be able to print the contents using php

Comment: Take a look at this [post][1] , it is the same topic.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750032/reading-file-contents-on-the-client-side-in-javascript-in-various-browsers

Answer (score 4):

@apanimesh061 you have to use the FileReader api

```
document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', CopyMe, false);
function CopyMe(evt) {
    var file = evt.target.files[0];
    if (file) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(file)
    }
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wAJe4/1/

it's documented at [Mozilla Developer Nework](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/FileReader#) for example

Comment: Ah! this is nice!
But when I load the file it does not show its contents in the text area ....

Comment: It did not work for me, could you please recheck your jsfiddle link ?

Comment: I guess you have to replace HTML code with
`<input type="file" id="files" onchange="CopyMe(this);"/>
<textarea id="myText"></textarea>`

Comment: @JoãoOliveira
That is also not working ... !
We get the path of the file but the contents are not displayed in the rext box ... what should be done ???

Answer (score 1):

If you are running this in a browser you can't read files on the client machine using JavaScript.

Comment: Kindly,have a look at the PHP code that I tried, dunno whether it is the correct way ????