# Html file picker with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, filepicker

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reading client side text file using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4950567/reading-client-side-text-file-using-javascript)

I want to open a txt file at client, parse it with javascript and post parsed data to a server page with ajax. I have scripts for parsing and posting. All i need now is to simply pick file from client computer.

What I need is something like this:

```
<div id="content">
     <button id="selectFile" onclick="return selectFileClick();" />
</div>
```

When user clicks button, a file dialog box appears and returns selected file. With this file name, I will make other operations like parsing etc.

```
function selectFileClick()
{
    var fileName = filedialog();
    // parsing file...
    return false;
}
```

Edit: I dont want to upload file and I have a custom design which doesnt look like;

```
<input type="file" id="file">
```

I need something like this: [jquery file dialog plugin](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/file-dialog)

Edit (2): I solved issue by this way;

```
$(function () {
    $("#button1").click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('#file').trigger('click');
    });

    document.getElementById('file').addEventListener('change', readFile, false);
});
```

at html;

```
<input id="button1" type="submit" value="add" />
<input type="file" id="file" style="display: none">
```

I hope this helps someone else ;)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4950567/reading-client-side-text-file-using-javascript might help.

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at this: [HTML File API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_files_from_web_applications)

That would probably be the easiest way to do it, e.g.

```
<input type="file" id="file">
```

Then just attach a function to the "onChange" function of the element.

EDIT: Just noticed that you're using jQuery, so you could really just do:

```
$("#file").change(function() { selectFileClick(); });
```

Comment: <input type="file" id="file"> is not always the best option. The browsers currently have hard-coded the text, and it is no way you can change it.
Can be "changed" (workaround) by putting in an overlay image or styled box on top of it.