# CSV to Multi-Dimensional Array. How?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, csv

I have been playing around with Line Charts using the Google Charts API and the following example shows a multi-dimensional array being populate into a data table then displayed on the screen.

It works great but I'd like to be able to populate data from a CSV file found in the same folder which may contain n amount of columns.

Can anyone help figure this out?

I think one would access the csv file with JQuery .get and then convert it into an array. I'm just not very JS savvy nowadays..

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses'],
          ['2004',  1000,      400],
          ['2005',  1170,      460],
          ['2006',  660,       1120],
          ['2007',  1030,      540]
        ]);

        var options = {
          title: 'Company Performance'
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: put up an example of your `csv` data

Comment: The example is just like the array shown in the google example.

Answer (score 0):

You should try the recommendation from [Reading client side text file using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4950567/reading-client-side-text-file-using-javascript)
It's JS way, from that you can turn each line into an array
Other method is by using ajax call to server side and then process the csv and return array
I think that will solve the crossbrowser issue problem.

Comment: I've try that but the chart just doesn't load.

Comment: which solution did you tried? ajax call or readfile from js? did you call drawChart() when the ajax call/readfile finished and modify the data?