# How to load local text information into <div> section

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to draw a diagram by using below codes.
It works well.
As you can see, I should put some text information in the `div`.
If there is a `sample.txt` which includes this information in local drive, can I load it into `div` section dynamically instead of putting it manually?

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html >
   <head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <title>Sample Diagram</title>
   </head>
   <body>
     <div class="diagram">
     Title: Diagram
  <!--   Participant FIRST
     Participant SECOND
     Participant D  
    Participant F
    Participant G     //--> 
    E->F: 2
     SECOND->FIRST: 1
     FIRST->SECOND: 1
     C-->SECOND: Request token
    C->E: 2
     SECOND->FIRST: Forward request
     FIRST->>C: Send token
     </div>
     <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
     <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.2/raphael-min.js'></script>
     <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.7.0/underscore-min.js'></script>
     <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/js-sequence-diagrams/1.0.4/sequence-diagram-min.js'></script>
     <script src="js/index.js"></script>
   </body>
 </html>
```

## UPDATE

```
/test/index.html
/test/js/index.js
/test/js/sample.txt
/test/sample.txt
```

## index.js

```
// js-sequence-diagrams by bramp <http://bramp.github.io/js-sequence-diagrams/>
$(".diagram").sequenceDiagram({theme: 'simple'});
$(function(){
 $.get("sample.txt", function(data) {
     $(".diagram").text(data);
 });
});
```

## sample.txt

```
Title: Diagram
SECOND->FIRST: 1
FIRST->SECOND: 1
C-->SECOND: Request token
C->E: 1
SECOND->FIRST: Forward request
FIRST->>C: Send token
```

### Without inner text

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html >
   <head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <title>Sample Diagram</title>
   </head>
   <body>
     <div class="diagram">

     </div>
     <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
     <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.2/raphael-min.js'></script>
     <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.7.0/underscore-min.js'></script>
     <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/js-sequence-diagrams/1.0.4/sequence-diagram-min.js'></script>

     <script src="js/index.js"></script>

   </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: `$('.diagram').text()` ? and by the way what do you mean by `local file`? File that was selected to upload or what?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I load the contents of a text file into a javascript variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/196498/how-do-i-load-the-contents-of-a-text-file-into-a-javascript-variable)

Comment: @Magesh Kumaar. There is a sample.txt in my local pc. Thanks.

Comment: @Sigularity I've clarified my answer. ;)

Comment: Here is a similar question: [Reading client side text file using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4950567/reading-client-side-text-file-using-javascript#4950836)

Answer (score 2):

Add a file-input element to the HTML page:

```
<input type="file" id="file" onchange="readTxT()"/>
```

And select `sample.txt` manually:

```
function readTxT(){
  var reader = new FileReader();
  var files=document.getElementById('file').files;
  var f = files[0];
  reader.onload = function(e) {
    var text = reader.result;
    $(".diagram").text(text).sequenceDiagram({theme: 'simple'});
  }
  reader.readAsText(f);
}
```

Comment: As far as I know, this is the only possible way to load a file client-side. +1

Answer (score 1):

If the `sample.txt` is available on the (http) server the site is hosted with (may be `localhost`), yes.

Assuming your directory structure is like this (/var/www/ is the server's root directory in my example):

- /var/www/

  - index.html (The file without the diagram content)
  - sample.txt
  - js/

    - index.js

Place this in your `index.js`:

```
window.onload = function() {
  $.get("sample.txt", function(data) {
     $(".diagram").text(data).sequenceDiagram({theme: 'simple'});
  });  
}
```

If you're not using any HTTP server, you can't load files from the file system directly - that's part of the Javascript sandbox (security concept).

I would then recommend using something like in [lx1412's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38824022/6377268), a manual file chooser is the only way how this could work then.

I've tested the script above using Firefox and an HTTP server; and [my edit of lx1412's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/38824022/revisions) using Firefox without an HTTP server.

Comment: There is a sample.txt in my local pc, and I am testing this one without any http server. With putting text manually, it works but I don't see anything in browser with your solution. -.-. Thanks.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I've made a mistake, I'll correct and clarify my answer.

Comment: I see the Browse button so choose the file manually but it doesn't show the diagram. I might generate the whole html contents in GUI application. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Sigularity What does the error log (inspector) say?

Comment: Sorry for late response. It just says "Syntax error" on the first line(of HTML) without other things. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest and easy way is to make `get` request to the server. And for that you have to use jQuery **$.get** function. Which will make a request for you.

Here is reference to **[jQuery.get()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/)**

**USAGE**

```
// make sure the PATH is correct for `sample.txt`    
// $.get(your URL to the file, callback function)

$(function(){
 $.get("sample.txt", function(data) {
     $(".diagram").text(data);
 });
});
```

Comment: sample.txt should be in http server? I am just testing this stuff on my local pc without that server. Thanks.

Comment: I updated the Question. Apparently, there is a sample.txt but it doesn't work.

Comment: The paths are ok now, but are you wrapping the code in `ready function`, i updated my answer try that.

Comment: On code inspection in browser, I see 'syntaxt error' on index.html(first line) and sample.txt(first line). I am not sure what is wrong. Thank you.

Comment: @Sigularity: I also see these errors, but only when opening this file directly (not via a server). I think you can safely ignore this.

Comment: @Sigularity may be you are testing in local but after all your project has to be uploaded to the server, right ? Then why you're not using a local server ? What you are doing not using a server is a bad practice, I would rather say that :-) hope you got my point.

Comment: No. I'm trying to draw a diagram on my windows application which provides a HTMLViewer so without any HTTP server, I can draw a JavaScript diagram, and that is my purpose. Thanks for the advice.